# Haskell error on input `|' Failed no modules

Tags: haskell, syntax

I'm pretty new in Haskell and I have got a very strange mistake:

```
insertion el [] = [el]
insertion el (x:xs) = | el < x = el:x:xs
                      | otherwise = x:insertion el xs
```

Which gives me this error, on the second line at the caractere just after the pipe:
parse error on input `|'
Failed, modules loaded: none.

I don't really get it,
would you have a tips ? 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: remove the '=' before the first '|'

Comment: Thank you very much ! There was the '=' in the tutorial I read so I could not imagin that would be the problem. Thanks again :)

Comment: What tutorial? Maybe it can be fixed without too much hassle.

Answer (score 5):

When you use guards (the pipe symbol) with function definitions, you do not follow the function name and paramaters with an equal sign. It should be written like this:

```
insertion el [] = [el]
insertion el (x:xs)
   | el < x    = el:x:xs
   | otherwise = x:insertion el xs
```

The first guard doesn't need to be on the next line, but that tends to be the general style.